# Reload or update Info on stage with phone app

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an phone app that displays certain text info, on stage, based on the day (e.g. Sunday, Monday...). When the day changes, Sunday to Monday, it should display Monday's info but it doesn't update when I test in the phone. I think this is because the phone holds the memory of where the user was. So, I need to make the app reload somehow, so it gets the correct info matching the day. I was thinking to do this with a user button (see below) but have not been successful with the reload. Any ideas please? Thank you in advance.

```
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler);
function fl_MouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
if (myText1.stage) {
removeChild(myText1);
}
else {
addChild(myText1);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That piece of code just removes the text from it's parent or adds it back.

What you probably want to do is to update the text property of it using the current day.

Something like :

```
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler);

function fl_MouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
   var days:Object = { 
      0:"Sunday",1:"Monday",2:"Tuesday", 
      3:"Wednesday",4:"Thursday",5:"Friday",6:"Saturday"};

   myText1.text = days[new Date().getDay()];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to put the function that gets the information, within a button function, which updates when the user clicks.